# Detect if the user is still holding the touch and didn't release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I wanted to detect the user touch release and if the user is holding it, the code down below

works, but dont tell me if i'm holding ( touch and hold and not releasing ) the touch...

please help me fix that

```
[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(holdAction:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];



- (void)holdAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)holdRecognizer
{
    if (holdRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {


       NSLog(@"Holding Correctly. Release when ready.");

    } else if (holdRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
       NSLog(@"You let go!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to this thing?

Comment: I have tried " UILongPressGestureRecognizer  ", but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with the `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` methods.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.isHolding = YES;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.isHolding = NO;
}
```

Where self.isHolding is a `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isHolding;`
**Note**: In those methods you may need to perform additional check if the touches have started over a particular view and also where they have ended.
**UPDATE**: Change your code accordingly:

```
[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress =  [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(holdAction:)];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:longPress];



- (void)holdAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)holdRecognizer
{
    if (holdRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {


       NSLog(@"Holding Correctly. Release when ready.");

    } else if (holdRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
       NSLog(@"You let go!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work, but i posted the rest of the code, please take a look

Comment: This must be working. The problem must be somewhere else? Other views above the image view? The place where you add the gesture recognizer?

Comment: I have placed the gesture recognizer inside viewDidLoad

Comment: THere was a socket code which was blocking the view, thanks just fixed it!